# Change the height of a list item when it's in edit mode

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have custom list item renderers and editors for a List control. I need for the editor to have a greater height then the renderer, i.e., the row should expand(in height) when it goes into edit mode. However, even when the list's variableRowHeight is set to true, it doesn't do what I want: the height seems to be based on the height of the renderer only, not the editor. Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the height of each of the renderers on the row that the editItemRenderer is on.
If my memory serves me correctly the varible row height takes its height from the first column cells (this may be wrong?)
If you have varibleRowHeight then when you go to edit a cell make sure all cells in the row are the same height and you may also have to invalidate the size and display.

If you have already solved this post your answer as it would be interesting to see what different approaches you may have taken.